# How can I get the element name from Materialize Scrollspy Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize, css-frameworks

I am trying to get the current element on from my browser's view using Materialize's Scrollspy plugin's getActiveElement function. Once I get the element ID, I want to add an animation class to it. I'm not sure how to implement the getActiveElement function option to retrieve the element id.

[Please refer to documentation](https://materializecss.com/scrollspy.html)

HTML:

```
<section
      id="projects"
      class="section section-popular grey lighten-4 scrollspy"
    >
</section>
```

JS:

```
<script>
const srcollspy = document.querySelectorAll(".scrollspy");
      M.ScrollSpy.init(srcollspy , {
        //getActiveElement: (not sure how to use this),
      });
</script>
```

Some help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

logged the element using

JS:

```
const scrollspy = document.querySelectorAll(".scrollspy");
      M.ScrollSpy.init(scrollspy, {
        getActiveElement: function (id) {
          console.log('this is the element: a[href="#' + id + '"]');
        },
      });
```